# MSBuild: MSB3061 - cannot access file because it is used by another process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, config-transformation

I'm trying to build me ASP.NET MVC project via the command line.

I am running this command: `msbuild /p:platform="Any CPU"`

In the project, we are using config transformations with MSBuild.
We have a Pre-build event looking like this: `"$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe" "$(ProjectDir)[MSBuild]\BuildSpecificConfigTransforms.xml" /p:Configuration=$(ConfigurationName)`

However, when I try to build using MSBuild, I get several MSB3061 errors:

```
(PreBuildEvent target) ->
  C:\Users\xxxx\Development\EPiServer\GIT\xxxx\xxxx\[MSBuild]\BuildSpecificConfigTransforms.xml(86,5): error MSB3061: Unable to delete file "..\connectionStrings.config.temp". The process
  cannot access the file 'C:\Users\xxxx\Development\EPiServer\GIT\xxxx\xxxx\connectionStrings.config.temp' because it is being used by another process. [path-to-csproj-file]
```

Does anyone have any idea what this is?

Comment: Do you invoke your `BuildSpecificConfigTransform.xml` from more than one project? That might explain the problem.

Comment: @SevaTitov Not as far as I can see, I can look more through later.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this error during my ASP.NET MVC deployment automation with MSBuild.

Could you check if

1) BuildSpecificConfigTransform.xml is open in any IDE (VS2012) or tool (eg: notepad, etc.,) during the time you run the build.

2) BuildSpecificConfigTransform.xml is in iis manager (win key +R and type 'inetmgr') application which is running.  If so, stop iis and run this script.

3) (Rare case) Is the file having enough permission?

I will be happy if this works.

Comment: I tried all 3, and none worked. I ran the command line in administrator mode, is that good enough for #3?

Comment: Running as an admin is enough.  'connectionStrings.config.temp' - Could you check the above steps for this file also.  Let me check and come back to you shortly.  It is of sure that 'connectionStrings.config.temp' is run by a process  in parallel.

Comment: We can try deleting the file manually by creating a target.

`<Target Name="delete" DependsOnTargets="$(Your Target Above PreBuildEvent in current build script)">

    <Delete Files="C:\Users\xxxx\Development\EPiServer\GIT\xxxx\xxxx\connectionStrings.config.temp" ContinueOnError="false"/>

</Target>

<Target Name="PreBuildEvent" DependsOnTargets="delete">
.......Your prebuild code...........
</Target>`

Kindly reply if it is still not working.

Comment: The error is because the file could not be deleted during the target execution. Lets try to delete it before the target execution. Please try the above code. I think it helps.